# PHP format split number into separate html tags

Tags: php, split, html

How would I go and split number `12345` into something like this with PHP:

```
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>5</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('((.))', "<span>$1</span>\n", '12345');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
$input = 12345;
foreach ( str_split($input) as $char ) {
  echo '<span>' . $char . '</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With [str_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

```
<?php 
$str="12345";
$str = str_split($str);

foreach ($str as $letter){
    echo '<span>'.$letter.'</span>'.PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = '12345';
$arr = str_split($str);

foreach ($arr as $char) {
  echo '<span>' . $char . '</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = explode('', "12345");
```

Then iterate throgh it with foreach and echo (or do whatever you want with) the tags.

Answer (score 0):

If the input string will be large, something like this will be more memory-friendly and possibly faster because it streams instead of breaking it apart first.

```
$string = "12345";

for ($i = 0, $j = strlen($string); $i < $j; $i++) {
    echo "<span>" . $string{$i} . "</span>\n";
}
```